# How do I connect an iPhone to my PC to load MP3s to it?

Tags: windows, itunes, iphone, mp3, music

How can I connect my iPhone to my PC so I can download mp3's to it? I also want to update the OS on the phone.

I have an iPod, but the connector doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: What iPod connector are you trying to use? iPod connectors are compatible with iPhones, except for the shuffle connector.

Comment: Your iPhone should come with a USB cable that you should use to connect it to the computer.

Comment: @Wuffers - I haven't found that to be precisely true. They're all physically compatible. But my older classic ipod connector doesn't work with my iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way is using the USB connector and iTunes. You can easily pick up a new cable at amazon.

[http://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-Transfer-Cable-Charger/dp/B000SSWFW0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SSWFW0)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 0)** Buy a compatible cable, [Deal-Extreme](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-cable-for-iphone-1-2-m-10562) is a great option. Make sure your iPhone model is listed. Note the cheap shipping takes approx. 5 weeks.

**Step 1)** [Download & Install iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/). Use it update your iOS on your phone. (iTunes will be like "Yo, dis 'ere eye-fone iz outta dayte dawg" - then your phone will be <strike>ruined</strike> updated upon your approval).

**Step 2)** Import your MP3s in to iTunes and load them on your iPhone

**Step 3 [*optional*])** [Jailbreak your iPhone](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-4.3-on-windows-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-ipod-touch-using-sn0wbreeze-how-to-guide/) and install [iDroid](http://www.idroidproject.org/wiki/Status), then figure that out too.

---

**Alternatively**

Perhaps you loathe iTunes, inspite of owning <strike>the iTunes-pusher</strike> an iPhone.

[Here's](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-sync-music-to-your-iphone-without-itunes/) a funky guide to iTunes-less music goodness on iPhone. (Spoiler: [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/), [WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com/)+[mlipod](http://mlipod.sourceforge.net/), [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/), [CopyTransManager](http://www.copytrans.net/copytransmanager.php), etc)

Comment: Maybe use Ernie's cable link, that's a wicked price - even though it probably came from the same place as DX, I'd put more stock in Amazon.